# Parsing a string as fast as possible that is using comma delimiters

Tags: c++, performance, object-oriented, parsing, csv

I have made a simple static parser for a bigger program. This parser takes a string that has comma deliminators and I need to separate the strings in to a vector for handling in a different section of the code.

I would like this to run as fast as possible so the rest of the program isn't tied up separating strings. I also need this parser to be robust, so I can't set how many columns it should have or anything like that.

For the life of me however, I can't seem to figure out how I can make this any less of a O notation. Right now it is O(N) because of the for loop, if there is something in the string. So worse case, the function is O(N). Is there any way to speed it up? I made this, because I have some special cases where if something has nothing between the commas IE ",," then it still needs to make a spot in the vector so the ",," can be placed in a CSV. Also if we need the parser to ignore a comma between quotes it can do that by setting a bool value.

The main problem, or what I would like to see is, is there a way to reduce the complexity of the function to less than \$O(N)\$?

```
//pass in a string and a vector and if quotes should be used or not and what     char should be used for delimation.
void Strtov::parse(vector<string>& inboundVector, const string& stringToBeParsed, bool quotesUsed, const char& charToSepBy)
{
    string temporary = "";
    //vector<string> retVal;
    bool quoteTriggered = false;
    //if we get an empty string do nothing. 
    if (stringToBeParsed.size() > 0) {
        //if the string has something in it then go ahead down the list. 
        for (size_t i = 0; i < stringToBeParsed.size(); i++) {

            if (stringToBeParsed[i] == '\"' && quotesUsed) {
                //if they are true, then mark them false, if they are false then mark them true
                quoteTriggered = quoteTriggered ? false : true;
                if (quoteTriggered) {
                    temporary.push_back(stringToBeParsed[i]);
                }
                else {
                    //place quote in to the temporary string and store it.
                    temporary.push_back(stringToBeParsed[i]);
                }
            }
            //place comma if the string is in a quote.
            else if (stringToBeParsed[i] == charToSepBy && quoteTriggered) {
                temporary.push_back(stringToBeParsed[i]); //<-push the comma on to the string because quotes are being used.
            }
            else if (stringToBeParsed[i] == charToSepBy && !quoteTriggered) {
                inboundVector.push_back(temporary);
                temporary = "";
            }
            else if (stringToBeParsed[i] != charToSepBy)
            {
                temporary.push_back(stringToBeParsed[i]);
            }


        }
        if (stringToBeParsed[stringToBeParsed.size() - 1] == charToSepBy) {
            inboundVector.push_back(string()); //if the last character is a comma then push an empty string on the end. 
        }
        else if (!temporary.empty())
        {
            inboundVector.push_back(temporary);
        }
     }

  }
```

Is there any way to improve this code? Obviously I'm the only one working on it, so forgive me if the names seem a bit rough. I'm not the most original in naming things, but I do try and make them descriptive enough for the average person to see what is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- There is no way to go under \$O(N)\$, just because you need to inspect the whole string.
- The test `if (stringToBeParsed.size() > 0)` does not speed up the execution; you may safely omit it.
- `quoteTriggered = quoteTriggered ? false : true;` is a long way to say `quoteTriggered = !quoteTriggered`.
- In

  ```
      if (quoteTriggered) {
          temporary.push_back(stringToBeParsed[i]);
      }   
      else {
          //place quote in to the temporary string and store it.
          temporary.push_back(stringToBeParsed[i]);
      }
  ```

  the character is pushed anyway, so testing for `quoteTriggered` is pointless.
- The remaining flow in the loop can be streamlined as:

  ```
      if quoteIsTriggered or char_is_not_separator
          push_to_temporary
      else
          substring is parsed
  ```
- Upon the loop termination, you don't need to inspect the last character - if it *was* comma, `temporary` will be conveniently empty. Just push `temporary` and be done.

Putting it all together:

```
    void parse(vector<string>& inboundVector, const string& stringToBeParsed, bool quotesUsed, const char& charToSepBy)
    {
        string temporary = "";
        bool quoteTriggered = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < stringToBeParsed.size(); i++) {
            if (stringToBeParsed[i] == '\"' && quotesUsed) {
                quoteTriggered = !quoteTriggered;
                temporary.push_back(stringToBeParsed[i]);
                continue;
            }

            if (quoteTriggered || stringToBeParsed[i] != charToSepBy) {
                temporary.push_back(stringToBeParsed[i]);
            } else {
                inboundVector.push_back(temporary);
                temporary = "";
            }
        }

        inboundVector.push_back(temporary);
    }
```

Comment: Those are really good points! Thank you, I'll definitely make sure to include those changes. I appreciate your help

Comment: In addition, you could reduce the constant multiplier from O(1N) to some smaller O(kN) where k < 1. You could, for example, fire up a few threads and have each process some number of strings at the same time.

Comment: @user1118321 it's a good idea, I might try threads in a later iteration. But the the amount of strings aren't to extreme so I'm not to pressed on going the thread route. Still my experiment with them thoughm

Answer (score 2):

This is less an answer in itself than a comment on @vnp's answer that wouldn't fit in a comment field.

There are a few things about his code I don't particularly care for the way they are. I've included comments explaining most of the changes I'd make.

```
void parse(vector<string>& inboundVector, 
           const string& stringToBeParsed, 
           bool quotesUsed,
           const char& charToSepBy) 
{
    string temporary; // automatically initialized to empty string
    bool quoteTriggered = false;

    // range-based for loop is preferable when it'll work:
    for (auto ch : stringToBeParsed) {
        // use `ch` instead of `stringToBeParsed[i]` throughout loop body
        if (ch == '\"' && quotesUsed) {
            quoteTriggered = !quoteTriggered;
            temporary.push_back(ch);
        } // prefer if/then/elseif over `continue`, when applicable.
        else if (quoteTriggered || ch != charToSepBy) {
            temporary.push_back(ch);
        }
        else {
            inboundVector.push_back(temporary);
            temporary.clear(); // clear() is designed specifically to empty a string
        }        
    }
    inboundVector.push_back(temporary);
}
```

Oh, one other thing: assuming you're using a recent compiler/library, you may be able to use the `std::quoted` manipulator to do this. It's really for reading from a stream (rather than separating a string), but allows things like:

```
std::string s;

std::cin >> std::quoted(s);
```

...which will let you enter (for example):

```
"this is a quoted string with a comma, in it"
```

...and the whole thing will be read as a single string. This lets you specify the delimiter (defaults to `"`) and the escape character (defaults to `\`). I don't believe it's quite enough to properly parse CSV though (but neither is any of the other code here). In CSV, the quotation mark acts as both a delimiter and a (sort of) escape character, so you can create a string that contains a quotation mark by using two quotation marks in a row where you want one to appear in the string, so this:

```
"Romeo said: ""Thy drugs are quick. Thus, with a kiss, I die."", and died."
```

...*should* be parsed as a single string containing quotation marks (but supporting this is left as an exercise for the interested reader).

Comment: That is neat. Right now, I'm using some parts of c++11, but really for the most part it's c++99 or is it 98? Any way, That is neat I'll have to try that some time.